# I am getting error in my MapReduce program,where I want to collect the highest temperature of the years

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

When I compile the hadoop command it ends up with the below error,
"java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable"

I changed the datatype from Text to LongWritable in that case I am getting other datatype mismatch.

Main Class:

```
public class CalculateMaximum {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException{

    Configuration config  = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(config);
    job.setJarByClass(CalculateMaximum.class);
    job.setMapperClass(CalculateMapper.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
    job.setReducerClass(CalReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(config);
    fs.delete(new Path(args[1]));
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
}
}
```

Mapper Class:

```
public class CalculateMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable> {

    public void cal(LongWritable key,Text values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        String row = values.toString();
        String []r1 = row.split(" ");

        //Integer year = Integer.parseInt(row[0]);
        Text yr  = new Text(r1[0]);
        Integer temp = Integer.parseInt(r1[1]);
        IntWritable tp = new IntWritable(temp);
        context.write(yr, tp);
        //context.write(yr, tp);


    }
}
```

Reducer Class:

```
public class CalReducer extends Reducer<Text,Iterable<IntWritable>,Text,IntWritable> {

    public void cal(Text key,Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        //Iterable<IntWritable> tmps = values;

        //int temp  = tmps.get();

        int max = 0;
        for(IntWritable temp : values){
            if(temp.get() > max){
                max= temp.get();
            }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(max));   

        }
            }
}
```

My input data will be like,

```
1900 39
1900 14
1900 5
1900 11
1901 32
1901 40
1901 29
1901 48
```

Expected output:

```
1900 39
1901 48
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up the job for the mapper output formats? Right now, you've only set the reducer output

Comment: Just now tried adding the below two Map output lines in the main class,but still getting the same error. Added line: job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
 job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

Answer (score 0):

I believe both key and value are int type. Can you try using the IntWritable for key ?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I used "LongWritable for key,since i got the initial error as that.When I made those changes, I am getting error as "java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.Text"